# Handwriting recognition library for Java

Tags: java, ocr, handwriting

I wonder, is there some powerful handwriting recognition libraries which can work not only with separate characters, but with whole words and sentences?

Comment: it works only with characters, but not with words

Comment: Dude what is a word but something made up with characters? What do you mean by work with words?

Comment: When you write you make connections between characters, and machine which recognize only letters can't separate them. I'm looking for an engine that can recognize the whole word or will be able to separate handwriting word into characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Tesseract-OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) , it seems to be a good OCR Engine

Comment: It's seemed to me, it was written in C. And I'm looking for Java libraries

Comment: Try http://sourceforge.net/projects/hwrecogntool, that's written in Java ;-)

Comment: Tesseract-OCR is primarily meant for printed character recognition and hence cannot efficiently be used for hand writing recognition